# Exponential of the number operator acting on an annhilation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

How do you show the following?

$$
e^{i\omega_{0}a^{\dagger}at}ae^{-i\omega_{o}a^{\dagger}at} = ae^{-i\omega_{0}t}
$$

$$
e^{i\omega_{0}a^{\dagger}at}a^{\dagger}e^{-i\omega_{o}a^{\dagger}at} = a^{\dagger}e^{i\omega_{0}t}
$$

Where $a^{\dagger}$ and $a$ are the creation and annihilation operators respectively.
I expressed the exponential factor as a summation:

$$
e^{i\omega_{0}a^{\dagger}at} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} = \frac{(i\omega_{0}a^{\dagger}at)^{n}}{n!}
$$

But don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: $e^A B e^{-A} = B + [A,B] + \frac{1}{2} [A,[A,B]] + ...$

Comment: @Mathphysmeister Is there a derivation of this expression that you could link me?

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula).

Comment: Quick Hint: 
$\hat{O}(t)=e_{}^{i \hat{H} t} \hat{O} e_{}^{-i\hat{H}t} \Rightarrow i\frac{d}{d t} \hat{O}(t) = e_{}^{i \hat{H} t}[\hat{O},\hat{H}]e_{}^{-i \hat{H} t}$. Compute the commutator, solve the resulting first order linear ordinary differential equation with initial condition $\hat{O}(0)=\hat{O}$.

Answer (score 3):

Two most straightforward approaches to such problems:

1. Calculate commutator $$[A, e^B] = Ae^B-e^BA = C,$$ and then use it as $$Ae^B=e^BA + C$$
2. Work with the matrix elements: $$\langle n|e^{-B}Ae^B|m\rangle$$ and compare them to the matrix elements of $A$.

Note to moderators: This is a homework problem, which is why I do not provide a solution. Instead I explain general a methodology for solving a broad class of problems.